# Segmentation fault in vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, dynamic-programming

I am practicing a dynamic programming problem called [the gold mine problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gold-mine-problem/) on [GeeksForGeeks](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/gold-mine-problem/0)

**My code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int test,i,max_rows,max_columns,temp;
    cin >> test;
    for(i=1;i<=test;i++)
    {
        cin>>max_rows>>max_columns;
        vector<vector<int>> v;//(20,vector<int>(20,0));
        for(int row = 0; row<max_rows; row++)
        {
            v.push_back(vector<int>());
            for(int column = 0; column<max_columns; column++)
            {
                cin>>temp;
                v[row].push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        for(int column = max_columns-1;column>=0;column--)
        {
            for(int row=0; row<max_rows;row++)
            {
                int add;
                if(column>=(max_columns-1))
                    add = 0;
                else if(row==0)
                    add = max(v[row][column+1], v[row+1][column+1]);
                else if(row==(max_rows-1))
                    add = max(v[row-1][column+1], v[row][column+1]);
                else if(row>(max_rows-1))
                    add = 0;
                else
                    add = max(v[row-1][column+1], max(v[row][column+1],v[row+1][column+1]));
                v[row][column]+= add;
            }
        }
        int max_value = 0;
        for(int row = 0;row<max_rows;row++)
            if(max_value<v[row][0])
                max_value = v[row][0];
        
        cout<<max_value<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On some unknown testcase I'm getting a Segmentation Fault

> Runtime Error:
> Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

I am sure that my code is not accessing any negative indexes as the code works when I initialize the `vector<vector<int>>` with the constructor below. (I choose 20 due to the limits of the matrix size in the problem)

```
vector<vector<int>> v(20,vector<int>(20,0));
```

I fail to understand why I'm getting segmentation fault because I'm making sure no indexes outside the range are accessed with my if-else ladder.

Comment: "I am sure that my code is not accessing any negative indexes as the code works when I initialize the vector<vector<int>> with the constructor below." that is no useful evidence. Anything can happen when you use an invalid index, the worst thing that can happen is: It looks like it works.

Comment: did you use a debugger already?

Comment: What are `n` and `m` when it fails?  Your code doesn't handle `n==1` correctly.

Comment: Also, why are you declaring a `vector<vector<int>> v;` and then using `v[x].push_back(temp);` where `temp` is a `long long`?

Comment: First I can't reproduce the exception, it runs without crashing for me (comment in code included). Second, the identifiers could be named more clearly, it's a bit hard to get their meaning on the first sight.

Comment: btw your style of naming variables makes the code hard to read. `#define ll long long` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` also does not help. The first is completely useless and the second makes your code non-portable for no good reason (lazyness?).

Comment: What I meant was my submission was accepted without errors, just by making the change of initializing my vector of vector to the maximum size given in the input constraints.

Comment: Look carefully at what your code does when `n==1`.

Comment: @Paulsor that the code runs without any crash or errors for you does not mean that it is logically correct and valid. You shouldn’t use that as an indication especially if the the claim is that it crashes.

Comment: As a note: you can always replace `[]` with `.at()` when accessing elements in a vector `at` does boundary checks and can help you to track down such an error if you have troubles to find it with the debugger.

Comment: Just browsing through your code, there is a x < n condition in your inner for loop. a x+1 in your if statements goes out of bounds, isn't it?

Comment: @t.niese You're right. My intention was that he provides us with an example input so I can hopefully experience the same error. It would be easier for me to get a starting point for research. Should have pointed out that more clearly.

Comment: @Paulsor the point is that even with the same input you will unlikely see the same symptoms, and if the code is wrong then it is wrong independent of input

Comment: @Paulsor it's an online challenge hence I could not provide with the input and neither am I able to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                else if(row==0)
                    add = max(v[row][column+1], v[row+1][column+1]);
```

The problem specification clearly states that it is perfectly valid to have only one row. But this code assumes that there are at least two rows.

This can (and likely will) crash if the input is `1 1 3 1 2 3`, which is perfectly valid input.